# Disable Mailchimp double opt-in in shopify

Tags: api, shopify, mailchimp

I'm new with shopify and mailchimp so I'm finding it a bit hard to implement mailchimp APIs inside shopify. Can anyone walk me through the process on where to add the API code and help me put up the javascript code to be used to disable mailchimp's double opt-in inside my shopify theme?

Every help is very much appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To disable the mail chimp integration, you can choose the Customize theme option----> footer----> disable the newsletter option OR just remove the Form 'Action' URL. (I'm using GRID theme, the steps might change for a different theme.)